# 3d simulation: setting up frustum, viewport, camera, etc

Tags: android, math, matrix, opengl-es, 3d

Learning OpenGL ES 2.0, using java (for Android).

Currently, I'm fooling around with the following to set up ViewPort, ViewMatrix, and Frustum and to do translation:

```
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)  // max, full screen

Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY,
            lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix,  0,  x,  y,  z);
```

Here's what I want to do:

In short, I want to display objects as realistically possible, in terms of their positions and shapes when they are projected on the device screen. (At this stage, I'm not concerned about texture, lighting, etc.)

Questions:

Suppose that I want to display a cube (each edge being  4 inches long) as if it's floating 20 inches behind the display screen of a 10" tablet that I'm holding directly in front of my eyes, 16 inches away. The line of sight is on (along) the z-axis running through the center of the display screen of the tablet perpendicularly, and the center of the cube is on the z-axis.

What are the correct values of the parameters I should pass to the above two functions to set up ViewMatrix and Frustum to simulate the above situation?

And what would be the value (length) of the edges of the cube to be defined in the model space, centered at (0, 0, 0) if NO SCALING will be used?

And finally, what would be the value of z I should pass to the above translate function, so that the cube appears to be 20 inches behind the display screen?

Do I need to set up something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step. Firstly, it makes sense to use `inch` as the world space unit. This way, you don't have to convert between units.

Let's start with the projection. If you only want objects behind the tablet to be visible, then you can just set `znear` to 16. `zfar` can be chosen arbitrarily (depending on the scene).

Next, we need the vertical field of view. If the tablet's screen is `h inches` high (this could be calculated from the aspect ratio and diagonal length. If you need this calculation, leave a comment), the `fovy` can be calculated as follows:

```
float fovy = 2 * atan(h / 2 / 16); //screen is 16 inches away
//needs to be converted to degrees
Matrix.perspectiveM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, fovy * 180.0f / PI, aspect, znear, zfar);
```

That's already been the harder part.

Let's go on to the view matrix. The view matrix is used if your camera is not aligned with the world coordinate system. Now it depends on how you want to set up the world coordinate system. If you want the eye to be the origin, you don't need a view matrix at all. We could also specify the display as the origin like so:

```
//looking from 16 inches in front of the tablet to the origin
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

Positioning the cube is equally easy. If you want it to have an edge length of 4 inches, then make a cube with edge length 4. If you want its center to be positioned 20 inches behind the screen, translate it by this amount (assuming the view matrix above):

```
Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix,  0,  0,  0,  -20);
```

Comment: Nio Shertler, thank you for your answer. Your solution seems very promising. I implemented what you wrote into my program and the cube shows up if I change the "setLookAtM"parameters to Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0). Is the "16" supposed be "-16"?

Comment: Strange. Have you located the cube at `-20`? The stated methods create a right-handed coordinate-system where the z-axis usually points towards the camera.

Comment: Yes, I see a cube. The following are the methods with parameter I pass into:Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -16, 0, 1, 0);

Comment: contines . . . Matrix.perspectiveM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, (float)(fovy * 180.0f / Math.PI), aspect, 16, 100); Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix,  0,  0.0f,  0.0f,  -20.0f);

Comment: You have defined your view matrix differently. Yours looks from `(0, 0, 0)` to `(0, 0, -16)`; mine looks from `(0, 0, 16)` to `(0, 0, 0)`.